# tire terms filter not working

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

I'm trying to achieve a "scope-like" function with tire/elasticsearch. Why is this not working, even when i have entries with status "Test1" or "Test2"? The results are always empty.

```
  collection = @model.search(:page => page, :per_page => per_page) do |s|
    s.query {all}
    s.filter :terms, :status => ["Test1", "Test2"]
    s.sort {by :"#{column}", "#{direction}"}
  end
```

The method works fine without the filter. Is something wrong with the filter method?! I've checked the tire doku....it should work.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is most probably being caused by using the default mappings for the `status` field, which would tokenize it -- downcase, split into words, etc.

Compare these two:

```
http://localhost:9200/myindex/_analyze?text=Text1&analyzer=standard

http://localhost:9200/myindex/_analyze?text=Text1&analyzer=keyword
```

The solution in your case is to use the `keyword` analyzer (or set the field to `not_analyzed`) in your mapping. When the field would not be an “enum” type of data, you could use the [multi-field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/multi-field-type/) feature.

A working Ruby version would look like this:

```
require 'tire'

Tire.index('myindex') do
  delete
  create mappings: {
    document: {
      properties: {
        status: { type: 'string', analyzer: 'keyword' }
      }
    }
  }

  store status: 'Test1'
  store status: 'Test2'

  refresh
end

search = Tire.search 'myindex' do
  query do
    filtered do
      query { all }
      filter :terms, status: ['Test1']
    end
  end
end

puts search.results.to_a.inspect
```

---

Note: It's rarely possible -- this case being an exception -- to offer reasonable advice when no index mappings, example data, etc. are provided.

Comment: Thanks Karmi, i've changed the analyzer and everthing is fine. Awesome support! :)