# How do I limit Tire/ElasticSearch results by association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, elasticsearch, tire

I have a collection of posts that are within categories and subcategories using a `belongs_to` association. Additionally, the posts have a `belongs_to` relationship with my state and city models.

I am limiting the display of the posts at the controller to those belonging to the respective location (i.e. city or state) by using a `request.subdomain` check on the subdomain in the URL. This works perfectly for everything except search using Tire/ElasticSearch.

For some reason I can't get Tire to limit search results to the posts belonging to a specific location. I've tried getting the subdomain into the model using a `cater_accessor :request_subdomain` in the model and adding a `before_filter` in the controller where `@city_or_state` is location associated with the subdomain.

```
 def set_request_subdomain
   Post.request_subdomain = @city_or_state if !@city_or_state.nil?
 end
```

Here's my model:

```
  def self.search(params)
tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: 10) do
  query { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:query].present?
  filter :terms, :published => [true]
  filter :terms, :request_subdomain => [:city_subdomain || :state_subdomain] 
end
end

def to_indexed_json
  to_json(methods: [:city_name, :city_subdomain, :state_name, :state_subdomain])
end

def city_name
  self.city.name
end

def city_subdomain
  city.subdomain.titleize
end

def state_name
  self.state.name
end

def state_subdomain
  state.subdomain.titleize
end
```

I need the search to limit results by the location (i.e. subdomain).

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE:**
I have followed [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/307-elasticsearch-part-2) railscast and been able to get Facets to work... I'm thinking maybe I can limit the items searched based on a Facet (i.e. without a user selecting a Facet as in the railscast), but I haven't been able to get that working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like that should work just fine, are you checking specific documents you have in Elasticsearch to make sure they actually have the subdomain you're filtering on, then checked the analyzer that is being used to make sure you're not searching on something different than what you think you're actually searching on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005220/tire-terms-filter-not-working

Comment: The part I'm struggling with at the moment is the logic to compare the `request.subdomain` to records in ElasticSearch with that subdomain... I can get it working with user selected Facets the same as the railscast, I just can't get it working 'automatically' based on the `request.subdoman`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
filter :terms, :request_subdomain => [:city_subdomain || :state_subdomain]
```

is back to front - the left hand side of the hashrocket should be a property of your tire index, and the right hand side that value it should match. Secondly, this is just plain ruby so

```
[:city_subdomain || :state_subdomain]
```

evaluates to just `:city_subdomain`, the 'or' doesn't magically make its way into the query logic

You want instead to say that either the `:city_subdomain` matches a certain value or the `state_subdomain` matches. You could do that with something like this, assuming that `subdomain` was a local variable or argument to your search method (far preferable to a class level variable)

```
filter :or, [
               {:term => {:city_subdomain => subdomain}},
               {:term => {:state_subdomain => subdomain}}
            ]
```

Comment: I have fixed the backward elements and implemented your `:or` filter suggestion... However it's behaving like an `:and` filter.

Comment: Perhaps you could update the question - it's hard to guess at how you might have changed the code

Comment: Turns out I just needed to move the `before_filter` to the `posts_controller.rb` file instead of the `application_controller.rb` and after putting the elements in the proper order (per your solution) everything worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the number of results to be limited, you can always run some ruby inside of your search block, and use the `size` and `from` methods.

```
search = Tire.search(Location.index_name) do |s|
    s.query do |q|
        q.string "las vegas"
    end
    # Best used for pagination
    s.size 25 # limit 25 results
    s.from 0 # start at the beginning.
end
```

I'm not sure exactly what you'd need, but you could always do something like

```
if something.nil?
    s.size 0
else
    s.size 25
end
```

That would be changing the limit based on some condition.